# how to serialize/deserialize list of objects in java?

Tags: java, class, serialization, deserialization

How can I serialize many objects of a Serializable class  in Java?

For example

```
public class Personne implements java.io.Serializable {

    String nom;
    String date;

    Personne(String nom,String date)
    {
        this.nom=nom;
        this.date=date;
    }
}
```

I wanna  create many objets :

```
Personne p1 = new  Personne("X","XX");
Personne p2 = new  Personne("Y","ZZ");
Personne p3 = new  Personne("Z","ZZ");
```

--> static function to serialize those objects

--> static function to deserialize

Full code  :

```
package game2;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

/**
 * 
 * @author ahmedJ
 */
public class Personne implements java.io.Serializable {

    String nom;
    String date;

    Personne(String nom, String date) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public static void Serialiser(Personne sp) {

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream("Score.sp"));
            out.writeObject(sp);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void Deserialiser() {

        Personne a1, a2, a3;
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Score.sp");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);
            a1 = (Personne) in.readObject();
            a2 = (Personne) in.readObject();
            a3 = (Personne) in.readObject();

            System.out.println(a1.nom);
            System.out.println(a2.nom);
            System.out.println(a3.nom);

            in.close();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Erreur de lecture " + ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] sd) {
        Personne p1 = new Personne("X", "XX");
        Personne p2 = new Personne("Y", "ZZ");
        Personne p3 = new Personne("Z", "ZZ");

        Serialiser(p1);
        Serialiser(p2);
        Serialiser(p3);

        Deserialiser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to write and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to read. Very simple and just works:

```
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(myFileOutputStream);
  out.writeObject(p1);
  out.writeObject(p2);
  out.writeObject(p3);
  out.close();
  ....
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(myFileInputStream);
  p1 = (Personne) in.readObject();
  p2 = (Personne) in.readObject();
  p3 = (Personne) in.readObject();
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote Me It just save the last object that I created

Comment: @AHmed show your full code.

Comment: i want to serialize many objets

Comment: You can write as many objects to the ObjectOutputStream as would fit into your hard drive. Write one by one and then read one by one as now shown.

Comment: I changed my code as you see above but i hade an exception Error

Comment: Just so you know its kinda expensive to initialize a new ObjectOutputStream/InputStream for every single Personne you want to serialize.

Comment: i have one question how can i get the number of a objets in  ObjectInputStream ?

Comment: Best, write the object number first. You can also call methods like [writeInt(int v)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html) on it. You can also try go guess from the file size but this is difficult as strings can be different length and in general you do not have precise control over format.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a static method to Personne like so.

```
public class Personne implements Serializable{
//Other stuff here
    public static void writePersonne(ObjectOutputStream out,Personne p){
        try{
          out.writeObject(p);
          out.flush();
        }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Personne readPersonne(ObjectInputStream in){
        try{
          return (Personne)in.readObject();
        }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You would just iterate over an array or a collection of some sort and write each one and on the other side read them in.

Comment: i want to serialize manu objets :p

Comment: i have one question how can i get the number of a objets in ObjectInputStream ?

Comment: Really there is no way to know for sure with just the ObjectInputStream. What I would do is when your serializing all your Objects the very first thing you should write to the file is the number of objects you'll be serializing and then you'd make a method to read that number and then call readPersonne that many times and return some sort of collection with those Personne's

Comment: @AHmédNet you don't need to know. Just keep calling readObject() until it throws EOFException. You don't need this count word prefix, and in most circumstances it isn't convenient to write it anyway.